# C++: How to decide the loop to continue to?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop, goto

I have Nested do-while, while, and for loops.

Is there a way to decide which loop to "continue" to? A variety of solutions would be great (not only goto..) Thank you!

```
while (foo==true) // loop1
{

   do
   {
      for(int i=0; i<someNumber ; i++) // loop3
      {

         if( soo==1)
         {
             <CONTINUE_TO_LOOP1>
         }
         else if( soo==2 )
         {
             <CONTINUE_TO_LOOP2>
         }
         else if( soo==3 )
         {
             <CONTINUE_TO_LOOP3>
         }

      }

   } while (moo==true) //loop2    

}
```

Comment: `continue;` perhaps?

Comment: continue will only bring you to the parent loop. It means to "loop3".

Comment: Simply avoid nested control structure whenever possible.

Comment: Solution two: rework your logic

Comment: Draw a flowchart on paper and find a way to avoid such a construction.

Comment: @Jessica `break` will you put to the next outer loop. There you may need another condition to decide `break` again, or to `continue`.

Comment: I have seen code that used nested loops and which solved a similar issue using `goto` and without the usual mess associated with its use. As another alternative, you could write an iterator-like type which has encapsulates the looping operations and in return provides the values for `i`, `moo` and `foo`. The body of the loop would then just contain the innermost code.

Comment: You probably mean `break-to`, `continue` stays at the same nesting level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can do this work around.

```
while (foo==true) // loop1
{

   do
   {
      for(int i=0; i<someNumber ; i++) // loop3
      {

         if( soo==1)
         {
              break;//<CONTINUE_TO_LOOP1>
         }
         else if( soo==2 )
         {
             break;//<CONTINUE_TO_LOOP2>
         }
         else if( soo==3 )
         {
            continue;//<CONTINUE_TO_LOOP3>
         }
      }
      if( soo==1)
      {
         break;//<CONTINUE_TO_LOOP1>
      }
      else if( soo==2 )
      {
          continue;//<CONTINUE_TO_LOOP2>
      }
   } while (moo==true) //loop2    
   if( soo==1)
   {
       continue;//<CONTINUE_TO_LOOP1>
   } 
}
```

Comment: May i know the reason it is down voted? This solution will surely work and i already mentioned its work around.

Answer (score 1):

CONTINUE_TO_LOOP3 simple:`continue`

CONTINUE_TO_LOOP2 easy:   `break`

CONTINUE_TO_LOOP1 this is the interesting one:

- cant do that in a single step without using the *four letter word* `goto`
- or placing a try-catch around loop2 and using a raise to get out.
- or assuming there are no code between the end of loop1 and the end of loop2:
   `moo = false ; 
    break ;`

Comment: http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: indeed, exceptions are another way.

Answer (score 1):

With some restructuration, and without goto:

```
bool loop3()
{
    for (int i=0; i < someNumber ; i++) {
        if(soo == 1) {
            return false;
        } else if(soo == 2) {
            return true;
        } else if(soo == 3) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And the loops become:

```
while (foo == true) // loop1
{
   do
   {
       if (loop3() == false) {
           break;
       }
   } while (moo == true) //loop2    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I advocate unconditional branches to expressive labels. Other solutions will cost extra conditional branches and possibly state variables, will be less flexible, and can be much less readable.

Comment: I also advocate ""Go To Statement Considered Harmful" Considered Harmful".